# Drawing lines between elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I draw a line between every h2 element on my HTML page so that I can receive the effect in the picture below? Initially, I would presume you would go about this by working out the size of the line required in-between the divs (divs are separated by the 1px horizontal line) + the distance between each of the h2s, but i'm not entirely sure how one could work out this distance.

[image: Thanks in advanced.]

Comment: The h2 elements are the two texts? What's (semantically, in the DOM) between them and what's its size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

a) find the position w.r.t document (i.e. by calling $(element).offset()) of the 2 elements you want to connect, call the positions p1 and p2

b) Append an absolutely positioned canvas to the body with a z-index to ensure it is displayed on top of everything else.

c) Draw a line between p1 and p2 on the canvas

This is assuming the elements can be anywhere on screen. If the line you need to draw is assured to be always horizontal or vertical, it can probably be done in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method. You can easily find the distance between elements using it.